# How do I successfully convert a double to string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, type-conversion, double

I have a purchased amount that I am trying to convert from double to string and I keep getting an error that reads 
*Input string was not in a correct format.*  on this line here`var amount = (ol.Amount*Convert.ToDouble(exchange)).ToString("0.##");`

**My Code**

```
var exchange=GetNigerianExchange();
var amount = (ol.Amount*Convert.ToDouble(exchange)).ToString("0.##");





private static string GetNigerianExchange()
{
    var forex = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=ZAR&to_currency=NGN&apikey=ZRH58691ZX2ENX1U&datatype=json";
    var JsonResult = "";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(forex);
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        JsonResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(JsonResult);

    dynamic x = jsonObject["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"];
    var exchange = (string)jsonObject["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["5. Exchange Rate"];

    return exchange;
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `exchange`?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen the value is 19.12489100

Comment: If you run `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble("19.12489100").ToString("0.##"));` you'll see that it works perfectly. So I guess `exchange` dos NOT have this value. Have you set a breakpoint an verified that exchange has the expected value?

Comment: What is the value of ol.Amount?

Comment: @Zidane: Did my best to get your error but it's impossible :D:D

Comment: ol.Amount is 26151

Comment: Code seems to work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You receive exchange rate from external source. So *"Input string was not in a correct format"* error can happen when you try convert rate string to double.
Use `TryParse` instead of just Convert to safely convert string to double if possible.

```
var exchange=GetNigerianExchange();
double exchangeRate = 1;
if (!Double.TryParse(value, out exchangeRate)) {
    // do something for case when you cannot convert rate to double
}

var amount = (ol.Amount * exchangeRate).ToString("0.##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```